# Mongodb C-driver install fail on windows

Tags: c++, mongodb, cmake

when build c-driver libbson, I have a CMake error

```
C:\mongo-c-driver-1.15.0\src\libbson>cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\mongo-c-driver -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"

CMake Warning:
  No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
  same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
  become a fatal error in future CMake releases.

-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.14393.0 to target Windows 10.0.17134.
libbson version (from VERSION_CURRENT file): 1.15.0
--     struct timespec found

CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/CMakePackageConfigHelpers.cmake:265 (message):
  Variable LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIRS does not exist

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  build/cmake/BSONPackage.cmake:10 (configure_package_config_file)
  build/cmake/BSONPackage.cmake:26 (install_package_config_file)
  CMakeLists.txt:378 (include)
```

and LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIRS is in BSONPackage.cmake

```
set (INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIRS ${BSON_HEADER_INSTALL_DIR})
set (LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIRS ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
set (PACKAGE_LIBRARIES bson-1.0)
```

How can i build it?

Comment: have you tried following the [instructions](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html#building-on-windows-with-visual-studio)

Comment: @AlanBirtles i tried this instruction so can you tell me what i forgot it?

Comment: Is your output above your attempt at following the instructions? If so read them again, if not post that

Comment: @AlanBirtles Have you ever build mongodb c driver on window os? i dont know so im asking the question.

Comment: not recently but the instructions look complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same CMake error when running this command inside the libbson folder C:\mongo-c-driver-1.15.0\src\libbson. Can you try running it in the C driver folder instead:

```
C:\mongo-c-driver-1.15.0>cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\mongo-c-driver -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"
```